# how to fill in gaps between polygons in Adobe Illustrator CS 6 and fill in the enclosed space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6, fill

[image: example of the kind of polygons (black) with gaps that need to become one]

Hi everybody, I have a vectorised image of line drawings resulting in the lines being converted to polygons. I need to complete the lines-turned-polygons by filling in the gaps. When they finally are, I need to fill in the empty space in the middle with black. I am working with Adobe Illurstrator CS6. I  hope anyone can help me since I a struggling with it for a long time. Thanks, David

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this can be done. Which method will depend on how accurately you want the shapes and possibly on how many you have to do this to. Here are  a couple methods:

The most accurate would be using the Pen Tool to trace around the exterior of your shape and then fill with black. This will make a new shape above your original tracing. I have my Pen Tool path already done and selected so you can see it.

[image]

Alternately you could just make several small shapes where needed with the Pen Tool to fill in the gaps. This would then require selecting the original shapes and the new shapes and doing Pathfinder> Unite to make one Compound Path. Then you would need to go to Object> Compound Path> Release (to remove the white hole inside). Then just select and delete the inner path.

---

Another way would be to use the Blob Brush to connect the gaps between your shapes. This is more difficult to do accurately but it is faster. Connecting those gaps will again create a Compound Path so you will need to Release the Compound Path and then delete the inner path to end up with one filled shape.

[image]